# How to get the Weekly or 7 days of the Date Range in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How can I get the 7 days or weekly depends on date range in formula fields of Crystal Report?

```
Example: 
   Date Range from March 01, 2014 to March 31, 2014 

Output:
    Week 1 (March 01 to March 07) 
    Week 2 (March 08 to March 14) 
    Week 3 (March 15 to March 21) 
    Week 4 (March 22 to March 28)          
    Week 5 (March 29 to March 31)
```

Comment: but if you see the calender week 1 of march is only `first of march` assmuming first day of week is `sunday` in the same way 2nd week is `02 - March to 08 - March`... are you sure this with your requirement?

Comment: No, it's not specific month and for example I will try to choose from March 1 to April 15 so it will automatically get the 7 days until it reached the last day of the time range as my example.

Comment: ok in this case Week 5 should be from `March 29 to Apr 4`?

Comment: Yes, then the last week should be april 12 to april 15.

Answer (score 0):

Custom function `RangeWeekSplitter` works within one year. Crystal Syntax.

```
Function  (dateTimeVar dFrom, dateTimeVar dTo)

// First day of the year
local dateTimeVar dBegCurrYear:= Date (Year(dFrom), 1, 1);

// Day of year (1 to 365 or 366 in a leap year)
local numberVar nFrom:= DatePart ("y", dFrom);
local numberVar nTo:= DatePart ("y", dTo);

local numberVar i;
local numberVar iTo;
local numberVar nDaysInWeek:= 7; // number of days in the week
local numberVar nWeek:= 0; // counter weeks
local stringVar sResult:= ""; // output string

for i:= nFrom to nTo step nDaysInWeek do
(
    nWeek:= nWeek+1;
    iTo:= i+(nDaysInWeek-1);

    if(i+nDaysInWeek > nTo)
        then iTo:= nTo;

    // generate output string
    sResult:= sResult + chr(13)+
        "Week " + CStr(nWeek) + " (" +
            CStr(DateAdd ("y", i-1, dBegCurrYear), "MMMM d") +
                " to " +
            CStr(DateAdd ("y", iTo-1, dBegCurrYear), "MMMM d") +
        ")";
);

sResult;
```

Usage example:

```
// Date range
local dateTimeVar dFrom:= Date (2016, 1, 14);
local dateTimeVar dTo:= Date (2016, 3, 4);

RangeWeekSplitter (dFrom, dTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DatePart` with `"ww"`, too. See [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic683.html):

> DatePart (intervalType, inputDateTime)
>
> ...
>
> ww: Week of year (1 to 53 with firstDayOfWeek and firstWeekOfYear determining the exact days of the first calendar week of the year)

Combined with `DatePart ("w", inputDateTime)` or `DayOfWeek(inputDateTime)` getting the day of week, you can calculate your first and last day of the current calendar week.

So for one specific date (`inputDateTime`), this would be your formula "RangeWeek":

```
Function (DateTimeVar inputDateTime)
NumberVar cw := DatePart("ww", inputDateTime);
DateTimeVar first := DateAdd("d", 1 - DayOfWeek(inputDateTime, crMonday), inputDateTime);
DateTimeVar last := DateAdd("d", 7 - DayOfWeek(inputDateTime, crMonday), inputDateTime);

"Week " + ToText(cw) + " (" + ToText(first) + " to " + ToText(last) + ")"
```

You need to give ToText the format strings you want, of course.

Example:

```
Input:  "August 23, 2017"
Output: "Week 34 (August 21 to August 27)"
```

That makes things easier in the formula where you get the date range.

```
DateTimeVar from := ...;
DateTimeVar to := ...;
NumberVar cw;
NumberVar count := 0;
StringVar output := "";
for cw := DatePart("ww", from) to DatePart("ww", to) do
(
    output := output + chr(13) + RangeWeek(DateAdd("d", 7*count, from));
    count := count + 1;
);

output
```